# deducing return type from auto input argument

Tags: c++, c++17

Why does the following fail to compile?
Can the compiler not deduce the return type from the input?

Don't fully follow the type conversion error being displayed.

```c++
auto func(auto &x)
{
 return x[0];
}

int main()
{
  vector<int> v = { 1, 2, 3};
  (void)func(v);
}

$ g++ -std=c++1z auto.cc 
auto.cc: In instantiation of ‘auto func(auto:1&) [with auto:1 = std::vector<int>]’:
auto.cc:15:16:   required from here
auto.cc:8:14: error: could not convert ‘(& x)->std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::operator[]<int, std::allocator<int> >(0ul)’ from ‘__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<int> >::value_type {aka int}’ to ‘std::vector<int>’
    return x[0];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`auto` as a function argument type **is not standard C++**. Nevertheless, `g++ 7 (svn)` accepts it... [and your code compiles](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/uZaC5B9k1SXeV4iQ).

Comment: Are you sure that is not proposed in future [C+1z](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B17) a.k.a. C++17 draft standard? I don't think that GCC adds many features beyond that proposal

Comment: Note that using `auto` to declare the type of a lambda parameter is supported in C++14.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: I think it's part of the Concepts TS, which is not (yet) standard C++17.

Comment: That should go into your answer.